# why warning appears when sending bitmap frame into MemoryStream to client?

Tags: delphi, sockets, video-streaming, filestream, indy

Before I explain my problem, I'm sorry for my bad english.
Okay, here my problem. when my Indy server sends bitmap frame to client, always appeared warning like this :

> "EAccessViolation at address 004DD42A..."

And error syntax blue highlighted on this :

> Athread.Connection.WriteInteger(MemoryStream.Size);

here my source code :

SERVER

```
 procedure TFormHome.TCPServerConnect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
 var
 NewClient: PClient;
 begin
 GetMem(NewClient, SizeOf(TClient));
 NewClient.PeerIP := AThread.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;
 NewClient.HostName := GStack.WSGetHostByAddr(NewClient.PeerIP);
 NewClient.Connected := Now;
 NewClient.LastAction := NewClient.Connected;
 NewClient.Thread := AThread;

 AThread.Data := TObject(NewClient);

 try
 Clients.LockList.Add(NewClient);
 finally
 Clients.UnlockList;
 end;

 procedure TFormHome.TCPServerExecute(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
 var
 pesan:string;
 begin
 pesan:=Athread.Connection.ReadLn;
 if pesan = 'video' then
 begin
 Athread.Connection.WriteLn('send');
 Timer1.Enabled:=true;
 FormStream.Show;
 Athread.Connection.WriteInteger(MemoryStream.Size);
 Athread.Connection.OpenWriteBuffer;
 Athread.Connection.WriteStream(MemoryStream);
 AThread.Connection.CloseWriteBuffer;
 FreeAndNil(MemoryStream);
 FormStream.Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Free;
 end;

 procedure TFormHome.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
 begin
 pic := TBitmap.Create;
 MemoryStream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
 VideoGrabber.GetBitmap(FormStream.image1.Picture.Bitmap);
 pic := FormStream.Image1.Picture.Bitmap;
 pic.SaveToStream(MemoryStream);
 //Pic.Free;
 //FreeAndNil(Pic);
 end;
```

CLIENT

```
 procedure TFormClient.TCPClientConnected(Sender: TObject);
 var
 pesan : string;
 begin
 IncomingMessages.Lines.Insert(0,'Connected to Server');
 TCPClient.WriteLn('video');
 pesan := TCPClient.ReadLn;
 if pesan = 'send' then Timer1.Enabled:=true;
 end;

 procedure TFormClient.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
 var
 Size : integer;
 ReadStream : TMemoryStream;
 begin
 ReadStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
 Size := TCPClient.ReadInteger;
 TCPClient.ReadStream(ReadStream,Size,True);
 Image1.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(ReadStream);
 Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Free;
 FreeAndNil(ReadStream);
 end;
```

what's wrong witha my code? i need your help.

Thank you before.. ^^

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to send the `TMemoryStream` before it has even been created.  You can't use `TTimer` or `TForm` in a worker thread (which `OnExecute` is called in).  Even if you could, when `TTimer` is enabled, its `OnTimer` event is not triggered immediately, but your code is expecting it to be.

You need to re-write your code to delegate **all** UI work to the main thread, where it belongs.  Try something more like this:

Server:

```
Uses
  ..., IdSync;

type
  TVideoStartNotify = class(TIdNotify)
  protected
    procedure DoNotify; override;
  public
    Thread: TIdPeerThread;
  end;

procedure TFormHome.TCPServerDisconnect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
begin
  TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(VideoStop);
end;

procedure TFormHome.TCPServerExecute(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
var
  pesan: string;
begin
  pesan := AThread.Connection.ReadLn;
  if pesan = 'videostart' then
  begin
    AThread.Connection.WriteLn('send');
    with TVideoStartNotify.Create do
    begin
      Thread := AThread;
      Notify;
    end;
  end
  else if pesan = 'videostop' then
  begin
    AThread.Connection.WriteLn('stop');
    TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(VideoStop);
  end;
end;

procedure TVideoStartNotify.DoNotify;
begin
  FormHome.VideoStart(Thread);
end;

procedure TFormHome.VideoStart(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
begin
  ThreadToSendTo := AThread;
  Timer1.Enabled := true;
  FormStream.Show;
end;

procedure TFormHome.VideoStop;
begin
  ThreadToSendTo := nil;
  Timer1.Enabled := false;
  FormStream.Hide;
end;

procedure TFormHome.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  pic: TBitmap;
  MemoryStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  if ThreadToSendTo = nil then
  begin
    Timer1.Enabled := False;
    Exit;
  end;

  pic := FormStream.Image1.Picture.Bitmap;
  try
    MemoryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      VideoGrabber.GetBitmap(pic);
      pic.SaveToStream(MemoryStream);
      try
        ThreadToSendTo.Connection.WriteStream(MemoryStream, True, True);
      except
        ThreadToSendTo := nil;
        Timer1.Enabled := False;
      end;
    finally
      MemoryStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    FormStream.Image1.Picture := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Client:

```
Uses
  ..., IdSync;

type
  TLogNotify = class(TIdNotify) 
  protected
    procedure DoNotify; override;
  public
    Msg: String;
  end;

procedure TLogNotify.DoNotify;
begin
  FormClient.LogMsg(Msg);
end;

procedure TFormClient.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TCPClient.Connect;
end;

procedure TFormClient.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    TCPClient.WriteLn('videostop');
  finally
    TCPClient.Disconnect;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormClient.TCPClientConnected(Sender: TObject);
var
  pesan : string;
begin
  with TLogNotify.Create do
  begin
    Msg := 'Connected to Server';
    Notify;
  end;
  TCPClient.WriteLn('videostart');
  pesan := TCPClient.ReadLn;
  if pesan = 'send' then
    TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(VideoStart);
end;

procedure TFormClient.TCPClientDisconnected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TLogNotify.Create do
  begin
    Msg := 'Disconnected from Server';
    Notify;
  end;
  TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(VideoStop);
end;

procedure TFormClient.LogMsg(const AMsg: string);
begin
  IncomingMessages.Lines.Insert(0, AMsg);
end;

procedure TFormClient.VideoStart;
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := true;
end;

procedure TFormClient.VideoStop;
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := false;
  Image1.Picture := nil;
end;

procedure TFormClient.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  ReadStream : TMemoryStream;
begin
  ReadStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    TCPClient.ReadStream(ReadStream, -1, False);
    ReadStream.Position := 0;
    Image1.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(ReadStream);
  finally
    ReadStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I am a little confused about this code:                                                            type
  TLogNotify = class(TIdNotify) 
  protected
    procedure DoNotify; override;
  public
    Msg: String;
  end;

Comment: when i put this code in the initial declaration, warning appeared that it can't find TidNotify identifier.

Comment: `TIdNotify` is in the `IdSync.pas` unit. It is a utility class to help worker threads run code in the main thread asynchronously, similar to `TThread.Queue()`. There is also a `TIdSync` class for running code in the main thread synchronously, similar to `TThread.Synchronize()`. The advantage of using `TIdNotify` and `TIdSync` in most Delphi versions is the ability to pass data, which `TThread.Queue()` and `TThread.Synchronize()` could not do until recently with the introduction of anonymous procedures.

Comment: +1 nice, when looking on the question I just did not know where to start to untangle ...